# Скачать файл с помощью QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, сеть, ftp, qnetworkrequest

Почему не скачивает по ftp ссылкам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**pesokWidget.pro**

```
QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = pesokWidget
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        widget.cpp
HEADERS += \
        widget.h \
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    w.resize(300, 50);
    a.exec();
}
```

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QLineEdit *edit;
    QPushButton *btn;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

public slots:
    void onBtn();
    void replyFinished();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QFile>

QStringList needToDounload = {
    "ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/slr/data/npt_crd/gracea/2010/gracea_20100108.npt.Z",
    "ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/slr/data/npt_crd/gracea/2010/gracea_20100101.npt.Z"
};

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *mainL = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    edit = new QLineEdit();
    mainL->addWidget(edit);
    btn = new QPushButton("Dounload");
    mainL->addWidget(btn);
    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::onBtn);
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
}

void Widget::onBtn()
{
    // берем адрес введенный в текстовое поле
    QUrl url(edit->text());
    // создаем объект для запроса
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    // Выполняем запрос, получаем указатель на объект
    // ответственный за ответ
    QNetworkReply* reply=  manager->get(request);
    // Подписываемся на сигнал о готовности загрузки
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &Widget::replyFinished);
}

void Widget::replyFinished()
{
    static int count = 0;
    QNetworkReply *reply=
            qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        // Получаем содержимое ответа
        QByteArray content= reply->readAll();
        QStringList l = QApplication::arguments().at(0).split("\\");
        l.removeLast();
        QString fullName = l.join("\\") + QString("\\dounloadFile%1.file").arg(count++);
        QFile file(fullName);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
            qDebug() << QString("Could not open %1 for writing: %2")
                                  .arg(fullName).arg(file.errorString());
            return;
        }
        file.write(content);
        file.close();
    } else {
        // Выводим описание ошибки, если она возникает.
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    }
    // разрешаем объекту-ответа "удалится"
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```